# How to recognize multi tables for OCR?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, easyocr

I'm trying to recognize and cut several tables

[image: Imagem de Exemplo]

I'm trying to adapt this code that recognizes the largest table in the image, but without success

```
# find contours in the thresholded image and grab the largest one,
# which we will assume is the stats table
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
tableCnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
# compute the bounding box coordinates of the stats table and extract
# the table from the input image
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(tableCnt)
table = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tesseract` is a powerful technology with **CORRECT PARAMETERS**. There is also an alternative way which is [EasyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR). It is also useful for optical character recognition. When I used your input image:

[image]

with the code:

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ch_sim','en']) # this needs to run only once to load the model into memory
result = reader.readtext('a.png')
print(result)
```

I got the results:

> [([[269, 5], [397, 5], [397, 21], [269, 21]], 'Featured Products',
> 0.9688797744252757), ([[25, 31], [117, 31], [117, 47], [25, 47]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9251252837669294), ([[513, 29], [535, 29], [535, 45],
> [513, 45]], '1%', 0.994760876582135), ([[643, 27], [687, 27], [687,
> 47], [643, 47]], '56.33', 0.9860448082309514), ([[25, 55], [117, 55],
> [117, 73], [25, 73]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9625669229848431), ([[505, 55],
> [543, 55], [543, 71], [505, 71]], '2.6%', 0.9489194720877449), ([[645,
> 55], [687, 55], [687, 71], [645, 71]], '59.66', 0.9955955477533281),
> ([[25, 81], [117, 81], [117, 97], [25, 97]], 'Lorem Ipsum',
> 0.9347195542297398), ([[513, 79], [537, 79], [537, 95], [513, 95]], '6%', 0.9802225419827469), ([[643, 77], [687, 77], [687, 97], [643,
> 97]], '53.55', 0.7060389448443978), ([[25, 105], [117, 105], [117,
> 123], [25, 123]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9813030863539253), ([[511, 105],
> [535, 105], [535, 121], [511, 121]], '2%', 0.96661512341383), ([[643,
> 105], [687, 105], [687, 121], [643, 121]], '51.00',
> 0.9972174551807312), ([[25, 131], [117, 131], [117, 147], [25, 147]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9332194975534566), ([[637, 129], [695, 129], [695,
> 147], [637, 147]], '$150.00', 0.8416723013481415), ([[23, 155], [115,
> 155], [115, 173], [23, 173]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9628505579362404),
> ([[619, 155], [711, 155], [711, 171], [619, 171]], 'Out Ofstock',
> 0.5524501407148613), ([[269, 203], [397, 203], [397, 219], [269, 219]], 'Featured Products', 0.9892802026085218), ([[25, 227], [117,
> 227], [117, 245], [25, 245]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9816736878173294),
> ([[513, 227], [535, 227], [535, 241], [513, 241]], '1%',
> 0.7698908738878971), ([[645, 227], [687, 227], [687, 243], [645, 243]], '56.33 ', 0.5116652994056308), ([[25, 253], [117, 253], [117,
> 269], [25, 269]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9332997726238675), ([[505, 251],
> [543, 251], [543, 267], [505, 267]], '2.6%', 0.5710609510357831),
> ([[645, 251], [687, 251], [687, 269], [645, 269]], '59.66',
> 0.9995503012169746), ([[25, 277], [117, 277], [117, 295], [25, 295]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9626429329615878), ([[513, 277], [537, 277], [537,
> 293], [513, 293]], '6%', 0.9771388793180815), ([[645, 275], [687,
> 275], [687, 293], [645, 293]], '53.55', 0.9578577340198124), ([[269,
> 313], [397, 313], [397, 329], [269, 329]], 'Featured Products',
> 0.9701894261249253), ([[25, 339], [117, 339], [117, 355], [25, 355]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9282643141918978), ([[513, 337], [535, 337], [535,
> 353], [513, 353]], '1%', 0.9946674557074575), ([[643, 335], [687,
> 335], [687, 355], [643, 355]], '56.33', 0.9876496602335217), ([[25,
> 363], [117, 363], [117, 381], [25, 381]], 'Lorem Ipsum',
> 0.9625460796304877), ([[505, 363], [543, 363], [543, 379], [505, 379]], '2.6%', 0.9337789031658965), ([[645, 363], [687, 363], [687,
> 379], [645, 379]], '59.66', 0.9949654211659896), ([[25, 389], [117,
> 389], [117, 405], [25, 405]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.931966914707057),
> ([[513, 387], [537, 387], [537, 403], [513, 403]], '6%',
> 0.9784907201549085), ([[643, 385], [687, 385], [687, 405], [643, 405]], '53.55', 0.5365941290893664), ([[25, 413], [117, 413], [117,
> 431], [25, 431]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.980995831244345), ([[511, 413],
> [535, 413], [535, 429], [511, 429]], '2%', 0.9679939124479429),
> ([[645, 413], [687, 413], [687, 429], [645, 429]], '51.00',
> 0.9964553415038925), ([[25, 439], [117, 439], [117, 455], [25, 455]], 'Lorem Ipsum', 0.9304503001919713), ([[513, 437], [537, 437], [537,
> 453], [513, 453]], '6%', 0.9744585914588708), ([[635, 435], [695,
> 435], [695, 455], [635, 455]], '$150.00', 0.9992132520533294), ([[23,
> 463], [115, 463], [115, 481], [23, 481]], 'Lorem Ipsum',
> 0.9626652609420223), ([[619, 463], [711, 463], [711, 479], [619, 479]], 'Out Ofstock', 0.5114405533530642)]

This results seems complicated because it gives the coordinates of detected texts firstly. However if you look into deeply, you will see that it is really good at detecting the texts.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcTSi0ZREDA&t=335s) also can help you for installation.

Comment: Thanks Yunus and Marcin, i´m try this code!